Redirect command output to file (append) and then append a newline character
I'm running the following one-liner:
cat input.txt | xargs -I{} bash -c './script.sh "{}"' >> output.txt

The script works and does exactly what I want it to do.
The only issue is that the output is appended in the file all in a single "line".
How can I modify this so that a new line character is also appended after each line is processed?

This sounds to me like the script itself outputs just one line. Maybe pipe the output to tr or something before doing the redirection. Either way, it would be helpful to know what the output looks like.

So, fix script.sh to print a newline at the end? Or if it doesn't/can't do that for some reason, print one from the scriptlet you have in the xargs command?

@ilkkachu How can I add a "\n" from the xargs scriptlet?

Try xargs -0, so each line is terminated by a null character.

Never embed {} in the shell code.

The correct form is as follows:
cat input.txt | xargs -I{} bash -c './script.sh "{}"; echo "\n"' >> output.txt

This was found after the comment made by @ilkkachu .

echo "\n" prints \n literally, then a newline character. Do you really need this literal \n? The question does not request it at all. In Bash echo -ne "\n" would print a newline only; but this is exactly what echo without arguments does in any POSIX-like shell. Do not complicate things and use sole echo.
